# How can I convert integers to corresponding strings in Vue markup?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js

I have a table for fetching data from the database. I used the "status" field for managing this table.

if the status is = 1, it means "Active" else if the status is = 2, it means "Completed" else if the status is = 0, t means  "Deleted".

Then I need to show the above status word in the web page table.
I used the below to show the status number.

```
<tr v-for="(depAcc, index) in depAccs" :key="index">
  <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ depAcc.created_at }}</td>
  <td>{{ depAcc.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ depAcc.status }}</td>
```

Please instruct me to show the status word on the table.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a data property containing the status map, like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    statusNames: {
      0: 'Deleted',
      1: 'Active',
      2: 'Completed'
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can reference that in your markup:

```
<td>{{ statusNames[depAcc.status] }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vue, anything inside double braces `{{ //this }}` is evaluated as JS. You can therefore write a method to return strings based on your status, then put a function into your double braces.

```
<tr v-for="(depAcc, index) in depAccs" :key="index">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ depAcc.created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ depAcc.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ statusText(depAcc.status) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in your page script, add this method

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods:{
        statusText(status){
            let message = "Unknown Status"
            if (status == 0) message = "Deleted"
            if (status == 1) message = "Active"
            if (status == 2) message = "Completed"
            return message
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is good, but a better pattern is to separate the data from the function. Your function could reference a map, as in my answer. Ideally a function should have _one_ return statement: `return statusMap[status]`. Also, method names should be more semantic, as `getStatusText()`.

Comment: @isherwood As to the number of returns a function should have, isn't the guideline "as many as you need for good readability" rather than a fixed number?

Comment: Sure, but good readability often _results_ in a single return statement, in my experience. In this case it's definitely cleaner to do so (once the data is excised from the function).

Comment: I updated the function to return only once and each conditional updates the message text.